# Cocos2dx Android with AirPush

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, airpush

I have a cocos2d-x android application that is working perfectly fine, till I integrate AirPush into my Android build.

I have added the api and app ids correctly. I have added the permissions. I have added the XML tags in the manifest XML file.

This is the last of the log:

```
E/cocos2d-x assert(14348): */cocos2dx/platform/android/CCApplication.cpp function:sharedApplication line:60
A/libc(14348): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 14424 (Thread-3289)
I/UniversalSDK(14348): Display Privacy & Terms
```

When I do not initialise the SDK, it works as normal. Once I initialise it, it can't even enter the start scene.

EDIT:
I used Revmob and admob as well.
When i removed them, it works alright.
So I'm curious to know what causing the crash...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `cocos2dx\platform\android\jni\Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer.cpp`

Line 18 to:

```
if (CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getOpenGLView()) {
    CCApplication::sharedApplication()->applicationDidEnterBackground();
}
```